# Compare all float values against an integer and skip to next iteration of the loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello I am new to Python and I am having some trouble with some test program I am trying to code. Just started a few weeks ago; from a book from my local library, so excuse how nooby it may appear:

```
print('''The next question will be having you find an exact number with divison Here is the question: with a 'value' of '420' what can you divide by to get '8' with a remainder?''')
value = 420
while value > 1:
    q2 = float(input(":"))
    if q2 == 0:
        print("You cannot divide by 0!")
        continue
    value /= q2
    print(value)
    if value is float(8):
        print("Correct Answer")
        break
    print("Next Question!")
```

So what I am trying to achieve here is once there is any value after dividing, such as 48 = 8.75 or any number through 8.xx, I would like the loop to stop and continue onward.

Comment: Please indent your code

Comment: Note, `if value is float(8)` has one major problem: don't use `is` to compare numbers, use `==`. Also, `float(8)` is sort of weird, you can just write `8.0`. But fundamentally you want something like `value //  1 == 8.0` or just `int(value) == 8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the loop to jump to the next iteration immediately, you can use the `continue` statement.

```
if value is float(8):
    print("Correct Answer")
    continue
print("Next Question!")
```

As a side note, you should not use the `is` comparison, unless you wish to compare equality of objects. Strings and numbers should be compared with `==`.

```
if value == float(8):
    print("Correct Answer")
    continue
print("Next Question!")
```

If you want to check for any value of 8, and ignore decimals, you can instead use int(value) == 8. This will cut off any decimals.

```
if int(value) == 8:
    print("Correct Answer")
    continue
print("Next Question!")
```